# Why are some square roots higher then the equation, and some are lower?

Tags: mathtools

I was writing this inequality, which contains two square roots.
Why is the second square root lower than the equation? I think it's because of the symbol I used inside it, but i couldn't find a way to fix it

```
\displaystyle\sum_{i \neq j} \sqrt[\leftroot{-1}\uproot{2}\scriptstyle x_i]{n} \geq n \times \sqrt[\uproot{2}\scriptstyle n]{ n^{\displaystyle\sum_{i}\frac{1}{x_i}}} \geq n \times \sqrt[\uproot{2}\scriptstyle n]{ n^n{\displaystyle\prod_{i} \frac{1}{x_i}}}
```

Edit: I don't know if it is needed, but i'm using the mathtools and mathabx packages. The error repeats on any root that uses the multiplication sequence symbol.

EDIT (Segletes) picture provided (in computer modern)

[image]

Comment: what is meant by \leftroot, \uproot, etc. is this any other package requires to run your tag?

Comment: They are commands used to move the index of the root around, to avoid the index part of x_i from clipping into the square root. Removing them shouldn't affect the code, but I'll try. Also i added the packages I was using, though I think only mathtools was used in that particular line.

Comment: While ugly, the result is what one would expect.  You will note that the math baseline is preserved in both square roots (see the initial `n` under the roots for reference).

Comment: You are right, I hadn't noticed that the letter inside was aligned. Would you have any suggestion as to how i can raise the exponent to get a better looking result? Should I ask that in a different question?

Comment: I would never use a summation in an exponent like that, just use `x^s` and define `s` separately, certainly never use a _displaystyle!!!!!!_ summation in an exponent. TeX changes the style in exponents for a reason, as you see here, all the `\displaystyle` and `\scriptstyle` are just making the output worse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ugliness occurs for several reasons, but is not incorrect.  First, the math baseline is preserved across both large square roots, and since the first root grows upward in size while the second grows both upward and downward, the disparity occurs.  This effect is compounded by the fact that the first large square root uses a `\displaystyle\sum` in the exponent.

I would use struts to try to clean things up.  I introduce two of them.  The `\mystrut` is used in each [large] root to make them take up the same large vertical footprint.  Then I also use `\mystrutx` in order to raise the exponent in the middle term.  Lastly, I also set that summation in `\textstyle`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\mystrut{\rule[-3.5ex]{0ex}{7ex}}
\newcommand\mystrutx{\rule{0ex}{2.5ex}}
 \begin{document} 
\[ 
 \displaystyle\sum_{i \neq j} \sqrt[\leftroot{-1}\uproot{2}\scriptstyle x_i]{n} 
 \geq n \times 
 \sqrt[\uproot{2}\scriptstyle n]{\mystrut n\mystrutx^{\textstyle\sum_{i}\frac{1}{x_i}}} 
 \geq n \times 
 \sqrt[\uproot{2}\scriptstyle n]{\mystrut n^n{\displaystyle\prod_{i} \frac{1}{x_i}}}
 \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Congratulations to become `Legendary` ;-) I missed it somehow recently...

Comment: Thanks.  Likewise.  I think it happened the other week when I wasn't looking.